# Codeigniter & Ajax - Console.log data returns CI's landing page in HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I want to `console.log` the result of my query using ajax, but it outputs the CI Landing page in the HTML Code.

**JS:**

```
 function getRouters(data)
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://localhost/ldcm/Main_controller/getRouters",
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }

$('#generateRes').click(function () {
   var data = userDetailsObj.data.homesize.id + userDetailsObj.data.floors.id + userDetailsObj.data.internetPlan.id + userDetailsObj.data.devices.id;
   console.log(data);
   if(data) {
      getRouters(data);
   } else{

   }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getRouters(){
                $data = $_POST['data'];
                $this->load->model('Query_Model');
                $data = $this->Query_Model->getRouters($data);

                echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

**Model:**

```
public function getRouters($data)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where('id', $data);
            $q = $this->db->get('selection');
            $response = $q->result_array();
            return $response;
        }
```

Is it supposed to print that way? Or did i miss a configuration part in config?

Comment: Direct hit URL in browser `http://localhost/ldcm/Main_controller/getRouters` and check what you got in response

Comment: Tried this, it takes me back to XAMPP dashboard

Comment: it means `URL` your using is not `configured` or `exist` on a given destination. Now try `http://localhost/ldcm/index.php/main_controller/getrouters`

Comment: Now it says Unidentified index: data

Comment: i did add an .htaccess file on the root folder, wait im gonna edit my post and paste my full code

Comment: As I assume your `.htaccess` code not working. Second, update your `controller` query. I'll put updated code in the answer for `.htaccess` and for `controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I assume your `.htaccess` code not working. Second, you need to update your controller code. Update below code:

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ldcm/
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

**Controller**

```
   public function getRouters()
   {
         $this->load->model('Query_Model');  
         $data = $_POST;
         $result = $this->Query_Model->getRouters($data);
         echo json_encode($result);
         exit();
    }
```

As you mentioned in comment you are getting errot `Unidentified index: data`. it means `data` parameter is not reciveing in `POST` request. Verify your `POST` request what you are getting. And replace `$data = $_POST;` with `$data = $_POST['parameter'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

`function getRouters(data)
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "http://localhost/ldcm/Main_controller/getRouters",
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }`

Comment: I dont get the page anymore after adding dataType, but no outputs as well

Comment: First you try print simple message in `echo json_encode('message')`. If it's print than check post data get properly in controller.